# Widgets not working correctly, can't drag and drop widgets into sidebars

Tags: wordpress, widget

Unable to drag and drop widgets into sidebars from within wordpress. We have 60+ sidebars, so is this an issue? How can we fix it, thanks. It seems to be working fine for all the sidebars except the last few, we can't drag and drop anything successfully into those. When I try and drag widgets into those, the widgets are moved to the sidebar 3sidebars above.

Have already deactivated all plugins, but no difference.

Comment: Is there any console error ?

Comment: which wordpress version are you using?

Comment: Wordpress version 4.2.2

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 2):

Dashboard > Appearence > Widgets > Screen Option

Click on Disable accessibility mode.

Comment: With this  option disabled I was at least able to add new elements to widget :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried having your page refreshed? You should consider having a hard refresh on the page by using **Ctrl** + **F5**. I also encountered this and the solution I get is having my page hard refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I installed the `Google Libraries Plugin` and fixed this issue. You can download the plugin from this [Link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/use-google-libraries/).

I believe that was some sort of JavaScript bug which was stopping JS from loading properly on the widgets page in the admin section.

This plugin is compatible upto 4.1.5. you can check using hit and trial iff it work with your wordpress version.

Comment: I am sure It is because of some kind of faulty plugins .. there is fix of this problem and its pretty easy way to follow . Here is the solution http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1UY0u-aZb-k. I just found this solution for you on stackoverflow

Comment: its not, I already deactivated all the plugins, and we can still open the sidebars, just can't move things inn

Comment: Hey! please check this link once. http://www.pc-freak.net/blog/how-ot-fix-widgets-drag-and-drop-not-working-on-wordpress/

Comment: please respond if you got solution

Answer (score 0):

for my case, I close another application I'm using like photoshop or illustrator. it work for me